# how to call a method on the component by clicking Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am use component of the dialog window **dialog.vue** from **vue-mdl** package

```
<template>
<div class="mdl-dialog-container" v-show="show">
  <div class="mdl-dialog">
    <div class="mdl-dialog__title">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions" :class="actionsClasses">
      <slot name="actions">
        <mdl-button class="mdl-js-ripple-effect" @click.native.stop="close">Close</mdl-button>
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import mdlButton from './button.vue'
import createFocusTrap from 'focus-trap'

export default {
  components: {
    mdlButton
  },

  computed: {
    actionsClasses () {
      return {
        'mdl-dialog__actions--full-width': this.fullWidth
      }
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },

  props: {
    title: {
      type: String
    },
    fullWidth: Boolean
  },

  mounted () {
    this._focusTrap = createFocusTrap(this.$el)
  },

  methods: {
    open () {
      this.show = true
      this.$nextTick(() => this._focusTrap.activate())
      this.$emit('open')
    },
    close () {
      this.show = false
      this._focusTrap.deactivate()
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to bring a dialog window to the other component

```
<mdl-dialog></mdl-dialog>
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised">Click me</button>
```

I found no information on how to call a method of one component within the other. All examples are mainly used props. Tell me how to do it?

How can I call a method **open()** in `<mdl-dialog></mdl-dialog>`?

Answer (score 1):

Since they're not parent child you'd want to use an event bus. Since you're using `.vue` files you can create a file called `bus.js` like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

Then, import that wherever you need to emit and listen for centralized events. Here's a quick example:

```
// SomeComponent.vue
import bus from './bus.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    log (msg) {
      console.log(msg)
    }
  },
  created () {
    bus.$on('someEvent', this.log)
  }
}
```

Then in another component you can do like...

```
// AnotherComponent.vue
import bus from './bus.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    emitClick (msg) {
      bus.$emit('Hello from AnotherComponent.vue')
    },
  },
}
```

You can read up a bit more about it here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: How do I use the bus in mdl-button, if I pulled it through npm? Why then need a method open(), if i don't call this method anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can create below helper method in methods in your parent component:

```
getChild(name) {
    for(let child of this.$children) if (child.$options.name==name) return child;
},
```

And call child component method in this way:

```
this.getChild('mdl-dialog').open();
```

I don't test it for Vue>=2.0